# LookupOrderedRows with WHERE IN function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'd like to build an array or collection which contains a list of IDs that I can then use to search my Orders Data Extension to pull the most recent matching record.

How can I achieve this using AMPScript in Marketing Cloud?

Here are what my Data Extensions look like:

```
Customers:
- ID
- Name

Orders:
- OrderID
- LocationID
- CustomerID
- Date
```

This is what I have got so far with my AMPScript, as you can see I can only search for individual LocationIDs, but I'd like to use the collection declared above the lookup.

```
%%[
SET @locations = BuildRowsetFromString('123|112|501','|')
SET @queryOrders = LOOKUPORDEREDROWS('Orders',10,'Date Desc','LocationID','123')
]%%
```

Comment: There are no arrays in AMPScript, only row-sets.

Comment: Yep, I've got this far already. The problem now is to search using that rowset.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for?

Comment: None of the lookup functions will do anything other than return rows that are exact matches in your data -- so any kind of wildcard lookup won't work.    Best you can do is iterate through each row and compare them to what you're trying to find.

Comment: I'd generally suggest pre-ordering your rows with a Query Activity before the send -- in order to reduce the complexity of the email scripting.

Comment: SSJS will provide you some additional array capabilities, but the exact lookup issue will still be an issue.